# Have you seen this man?

Tags: discussion, support

I [wrote this warning on Judaism's meta site](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1885/have-you-seen-this-man), however I wanted to also give this community a head's up - as this is the sort of site that the individual is likely to want to disrupt with his antics.

The Stack Exchange community team has been made aware of it, and will be on the lookout. This is here just so you know who you're dealing with should he show up, and the advice provided by SE in the answer to the linked meta post is also valid here.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, I've edited your post a bit since you have a copy of it (and the answer we left) on Judaism's meta site. We're aware of it, and we'll be on the watch.

Comment: @TimPost - NP. Thanks.